# Visual Studio Live Testing - Start failed because TestPlatform V2 can not be located

Tags: unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2017

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get live testing to start in Visual studio 2017 (15.3.5)

I get this error:
Start failed because TestPlatform V2 can not be located. Please try to modify your Visual Studio installation through Microsoft Visual Studio Installer, and make sure `Testing tools core features` is selected under `Individual components -> Debugging and testing`
[13:23:22.396 Info] For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=852911.

I have installed the required component and it still won't run. Although the tests will run if I manually run them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have started seeing the same symptoms; VS Enterprise 15.4.1 on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

Comment: I also having the same problem. Does anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi i also had the similar problem. After checking **Extentions and Updates** in Vs 2017, the extention **Dotnet Extention for test explorer** disabled. After enabling this its worked
[image: Enabling **Dotnet Extention for test explore**]

Comment: I also had this plugin disabled. I enabled this and it resolved the issue.  Curiously, it took more than one attempt to get the extension to enable.  At first I thought it hadn't worked, but then I rechecked and the extension was still disabled for some reason.  Once enabled, Live Unit Testing was functioning again.